# How to refresh select/radio input (after saving to local DB)

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I just want to refresh my selects/radio buttons AFTER performing one of my database calls. I perform them and the select menus aren't refreshing, I don't know how to handle this situation. ( i am aware of selectmenu.('refresh') I used it in this same code just not AFTER one of my database calls)

**Scenario**

I am writing a web application using JQuery for the techs at my company. They will be able to fill forms out and submit them directly to our database. If there is no internet connection, the user can just save their values onto the local database, so when there is an internet connection they can send it later. There are three menus, Basic information, Lighting Schedules with on and off hours, and a local database.

Here is the JSFiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/QQUnx/6/

**Problem**
After saving into the local database (Opening the collapsible and pushing create, all basic information MUST be filled out first), the input slots values are set to "". The problem here though is that the select menus and the radio button labeled HVAC are not refreshed. Their old values still show. I am aware they are not being refreshed, I have tried a few different ways to fix this but am having a hard time figuring this one out... Any ideas?

**NOTE:** The only fields that are currently associated with the database are "project number, site name, contact name, tech name, Area #1 Description, HVAC #1, and Monday's ON hour" These are the only fields that should be set back to null as of now. So for testing purposes we want to refresh the **HVAC #1** and the first Time option labeled **Monday ON**

Try to get these two refreshing for now. Once I get these ones working I will write more to the Database.js file to have it save and refresh these values as well.

**Proper Solution** a JSFiddle with a refresh executed on the HVAC radio button and/or first select menu (labeled Monday On) AFTER the onCreate function is called. The select menu is more important.
**You can see Monday on's value saved and appended to the list when pushing Create.**

Thanks.

Comment: please feel free to ask questions, I tried to be as clear as I could but understand if this can be a bit confusing at first.

Comment: In you HVAC and Monday, you dont have a default value like "Please select..", always its being defaulted to the 0th value of the select box. So once your local save is done why not set the index of that select to 0. This is just a thought.

Comment: I believe even if you set the index to 0, you would still have to use selectmenu("refresh") afterwards. In fact, the index of the first select IS actually being set to 0 after create is pushed. Currently Database.js create function is where this is done. The question becomes where do I put the refresh and how do I do it. I just need the refresh to work, on that Monday box after Create is pushed. . .

Comment: I just took a look at the code in Database.js. If i am not wrong, you have function called updateForm() for which you are passing empty strings for all the parameters once the create/update is successful, for text fields this will set the empty values but for select's since you dont have added an empty value in the select it may not find the value to set and it will not reset the value. Am i making sense?

Comment: I understand what you are saying, and the way you are explaining updateForm is perfectly correct. However, On does have an empty value. and Also, I can see that it is in fact being changed because if you push create and save some time in that select box, and then updateForm is performed. Click that select box, and you see that its value is set to ON. If you click the select box before you push create, you can see the value is clearly whatever you set it to. The value does change, the buttons appearance does not. So yes.. you are making sense. Am I? O_o

Comment: May be you can pass the default values for the select and check whether its resetting...for example on load the hvac is default to No right you can pass the string "No" to this updateForm method in the place of hvac and see whether it does the trick or not.

Comment: Yes, that is a good and necessary suggestion raddyKrish, for the HVAC radio button. A refresh will still need to be called afterwards though. and that is the 'problem' i am having

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10417/discussion-between-mob-and-raddykrish)